# Why does this code displays "paper"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm trying this JavaScript code, which is an exercise in **Codeacademy** website.
But problem is that it shows "**paper**" in console. It should display "**scissors**"?
What is the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var userChoice= prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors");
var computerChoice=0.35;
console.log(computerChoice);
if(0<computerChoice<0.33){
    computerChoice="rock";
}
else if(0.34<computerChoice<0.66){
    computerChoice="scissors";
}
else{
    computerChoice="paper";
}
console.log(computerChoice);
```

Comment: `0<computerChoice<0.33` is not right...

Comment: `0<computerChoice<0.33` => `true < 0.33` => `false`, same goes for the next, so `"paper"` is the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
x < y < z
```

is evaluated as

```
(x < y) < z
```

Which in your case,

```
0 < computerChoice < 0.33
>> (0 < computerChoice) < 0.33
>> true < 0.33
>> false //always
```

*Side-Note : The same applies to equality operators too. `x == y == z`

Answer (score 3):

You need to break up the less than, greater than checks into two parts.

```
if(computerChoice>0 && computerChoice<0.33){
```

And the same thing needs to be done to the other.

Comment: Yup. epascarello right on point here. Comparison operators are made exactly for this purpose. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 2):

You can't write expressions like

```
if(0 < computerChoice < 0.33)
```

in Javascript. You have to split it up into two expressions:

```
if(0 < computerChoice && computerChoice < 0.33)
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well the reason why this is not working for you because TRUE is not smaller than 0.66. The expression will be calculated like this 
`(0.36 < computerChoice ) => true if (computerchoice = 0.35 )`
Now next part is ( true < 0.66 ) which is false. So expression evaluates to be false. `Approach: 0.34<computerChoice==computerChoice<0.66`
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong syntax. `a < b < c` is not valid JavaScript. You have to create two conditionals in the block.

```
if ( 0 < computerChoice < 0.33)
```

should be

```
if (computerChoice > 0 && computerChoice < 0.33)
```

Check out this snippet.

```js
var cpuChoice = document.getElementById("cpu-selection");

var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors");
var computerChoice = 0.35;
//console.log(computerChoice);
if (computerChoice > 0 && computerChoice < 0.33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if (computerChoice > 0.34 && computerChoice < 0.66) {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
else {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}

cpuChoice.innerHTML = computerChoice;
```

```html
<p id="cpu-selection"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think range based inequalities are illegal in JavaScript, an inequality on the left and right. because JavaScript is weakly typed my guess is it will evaluate one inequality and get a true or false value, then cast that to a number.

my guess is 0 < computer choice is true which will be cast to 1 which if greater than. 33, for the second if .34 < computer choice which is true and cast to 1 which is > .66 so that's false, so the else statement is evaluated

try something like `0 < computerChoice&& computerChoice < .33` etc.

*edit*: I got back to a computer and was able to test this, I experienced these results in google chrome

```
true < 1 // false
true > 1 // false
true == 1 // true
```

(note: experiences may differ, i wouldn't call this behavior well-defined coming from typically more strongly typed languages, but it possibly could be well-defined as this behavior in JavaScript)

Comment: just note all of the operators are _binary operators_ which means they take two, and only two, operands, and are then evaluated according to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Since you used this:

```
if(computerChoice < 0.33){ ... }
```

And your next statement is an `else if`, you can actually remove the `0.34<` from your second `if`, as it's already given that it is larger than 0.34, as the `if` before was false.

```
if(computerChoice < 0.33){
    computerChoice = "rock";
}else if(computerChoice < 0.66){
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}else{
    computerChoice = "paper";
}
```

You did not need to check for computerChoice being less than 0 either, as Math.random always returns values between 0 and 1.